# Why Apache IoTDB encountered OOM problem when doing tsfile flushing?

Tags: apache-iotdb, iotdb

Has anyone encountered OOM problem when flushing tsfile in Apache IoTDB? The error message is like: ERROR o.a.i.d.e.s.TsFileProcessor:1047 - root.data/0: /opt/iotdb/./sbin/../data/data/sequence/root.data/0/0/1688383388042-19-0-0.tsfile meet error when Flushing a memtable, changing system mode to error java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.lang.OutOfMemoryError. How should I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check if when the Apache IoTDB server execute `seq tsfile` command, an automatical compaction will also be executed. If so, this may cause OOM, so you can turn this compaction operation off to solve your problem.